# Using Multiple JQuery - Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

**Situation:**

1) Using add / subtract buttons to add or remove rows with multiple data inputs.

2) Also running javascript to calculate height and width into a sqfoot measurement.

**Problems:**

1) The javascript calculation works great on the first field, when I copy that same code and replace the 1's with 2, 3 etc... Nothing happens in subsequent fields.

-Verified by inspecting the code that all inputs are being labeled correctly.

2) Is there a way to redo this calculation javascript to where it can also run off the +counter function I am using, so I don't have to make a code for 1-60?

3) (smaller issue) When the form does duplicate a row, it looks almost identical but the spacing between each input is a little smaller, I can't find anything in my code that would cause this.

**Other Details:**

I am using jquery 1.6.2 primarily for this site.

I do have jquery 1.3.2 loading in no conflict for the script that is adding more rows.

**CODE:**

```js
/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
 *  Multiply Form
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------  
 */

$('#sheight1, #swidth1').keyup(function(){
    var sheight1 = parseFloat($('#sheight1').val()) || 0;
    var swidth1 = parseFloat($('#swidth1').val()) || 0;
    var swidth1r = 6 * Math.round( swidth1 / 6 );
    var sheight1r = 6 * Math.round( sheight1 / 6 );
    $('#ssqfoot1').val(sheight1r * swidth1r / 144);    
});

$('#sheight2, #swidth2').keyup(function(){
    var sheight2 = parseFloat($('#sheight2').val()) || 0;
    var swidth2 = parseFloat($('#swidth2').val()) || 0;
    var swidth2r = 6 * Math.round( swidth2 / 6 );
    var sheight2r = 6 * Math.round( sheight2 / 6 );
    $('#ssqfoot2').val(sheight2r * swidth2r / 144);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$j(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $j("#addButton").click(function () {

 if(counter>60){
            alert("Max 60 Standard Shutters Per Order");
            return false;
 }

 var newStandardDiv = $j(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr({"name":'StandardDiv' + counter, "id":'StandardDiv' + counter,});       
    
 newStandardDiv.after().html(
    
  '<span style="margin-right:15px">Room: ' +
       '<input class="text" type="text" name="sroom' + counter + '" id="sroom' + counter + '" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px">' +
  '</span>' +
  
  '<span style="margin-right:15px; height=90px">Width: ' +
         '<input class="text" type="number" name="swidth' + counter + '" id="swidth' + counter + '"   style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0"  title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' +
     '</span>' +
                            
        '<span style="margin-right:15px">Height: ' +
          '<input class="text" type="number" name="sheight' + counter + '" id="sheight' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' +
     '</span>' +
                            
                            
         

          '<span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Rect.' +
           '<input class="text" type="number" name="ssqfoot' + counter + '" id="ssqfoot' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly />' +
       '</span>' +
    '</div>'
 
 
 );

 newStandardDiv.appendTo("#StandardGroup");

 var objDiv = document.getElementById("StandardGroup");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    

 counter++;
     });

     $j("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if(counter==2){
          alert("Nothing To Remove");
          return false;
       }

 counter--;

        $j("#StandardDiv" + counter).remove();

     });
  });
</script>


<div id="StandardGroup" style="max-height:440px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:2px">
 <div id="StandardDiv1" >
                           
                           <span style="margin-right:15px">Room: 
                            <input class="text" type="text" name="sroom1" id="sroom1" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px"></span>
                            
                            <span style="margin-right:15px; height=90px">Width: 
                            <input class="text" type="number" name="swidth1" id="swidth1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values." value=""></span>
                            
                            <span style="margin-right:15px">Height: 
                            <input class="text" type="number" name="sheight1" id="sheight1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values."></span>
                                                        

                            <span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Rect.
                            <input class="text" type="number" name="ssqfoot1" id="ssqfoot1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly /></span>
 </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="button light" value="+" id="addButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; margin-left:13px;">
<input type="button" class="button light" value="-" id="removeButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**note: calculator needs at least 3x3 input before it would display result for sqfoot.

Upon further inspection I believe some of my problem stems from the fact I am running multiple instances of JQuery.

Is there a way to either, make the script I'm using to duplicate the rows work in 1.6.2, or, make the javascript I am running to calculate square feet work in 1.3.2?

any help would be immensely appreciated, cheers!

Comment: start using css class names instead of id as selectors

Comment: Sorry, I am by no means an expert at this sort of thing. I just search the web on a case by case basis as I run into things I don't know how to do.

could you please provide an example of how I would use css class names as a selector to solve this problem?

Comment: `Please write proper title of this question`

Comment: there you go, vic.

Comment: Do you need this old versions of jquery, namely 1.3.2 and 1.6.2. This problem can be solved but with later versions of jquery easily.

Answer (score 0):

First use class instead of id for inputs. Also when you create an html element dynamically you need to add id or class of it's static parent element in the event listener. You can try the below code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>   

</head>

<body>
<div id="StandardGroup" style="max-height:440px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:2px">
<div id="StandardDiv1" >

                       <span style="margin-right:15px">Room: 
                        <input class="sroom" type="text" name="sroom1" id="sroom1" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px"></span>

                        <span style="margin-right:15px; height=90px">Width: 
                        <input class="swidth" type="number" name="swidth1" id="swidth1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values." value=""></span>

                        <span style="margin-right:15px">Height: 
                        <input class="sheight" type="number" name="sheight1" id="sheight1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values."></span>


                        <span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Rect.
                        <input class="ssqfoot" type="number" name="ssqfoot1" id="ssqfoot1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly /></span>
</div>
 </div>
 <input type="button" class="button light" value="+" id="addButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; margin-left:13px;">
 <input type="button" class="button light" value="-" id="removeButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
 </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$j(document).ready(function(){

  $('#StandardGroup').on('keyup','.sheight, .swidth',function(){
    console.log($(this).parents().eq(1).find('.sheight').val());
    var sheight1 = parseFloat($(this).parents().eq(1).find('.sheight').val()) || 0;
    var swidth1 = parseFloat($(this).parents().eq(1).find('.swidth').val()) || 0;
    var swidth1r = 6 * Math.round( swidth1 / 6 );
    var sheight1r = 6 * Math.round( sheight1 / 6 );
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.ssqfoot').val(sheight1r * swidth1r / 144);    
 });

var counter = 2;

$j("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>60){
        alert("Max 60 Standard Shutters Per Order");
        return false;
}

var newStandardDiv = $j(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr({"name":'StandardDiv' + counter, "id":'StandardDiv' + counter,});             

newStandardDiv.after().html(

    '<span style="margin-right:15px">Room: ' +
      '<input class="sroom" type="text" name="sroom' + counter + '" id="sroom' + counter + '" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px">' +
    '</span>' +

    '<span style="margin-right:15px; height=90px">Width: ' +
     '<input class="swidth" type="number" name="swidth' + counter + '" id="swidth' + counter + '"   style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0"  title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' +
    '</span>' +

    '<span style="margin-right:15px">Height: ' +
      '<input class="sheight" type="number" name="sheight' + counter + '" id="sheight' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' +
    '</span>' +
      '<span style="margin-right:15px">Sq. Ft. Rect.' +
       '<input class="ssqfoot" type="number" name="ssqfoot' + counter + '" id="ssqfoot' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly />' +
      '</span>' +
      '</div>'
    );

  newStandardDiv.appendTo("#StandardGroup");

  var objDiv = document.getElementById("StandardGroup");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;


   counter++;
   });

 $j("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==2){
      alert("Nothing To Remove");
      return false;
   }

counter--;

    $j("#StandardDiv" + counter).remove();

 });
  });

   </script>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you can, use jquery 2.1.1 atleast now. Versions this old better not be used at all for jquery. The code below uses [.on function of jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from jquery 2.1.1. This makes sure that even dynamically added controls get the desired functionality even when added later on page.

**Problems you mentioned:**

> 1) The javascript calculation works great on the first field, when I copy that same code and replace the 1's with 2, 3 etc... Nothing happens in subsequent fields.

**Answer:** Nothing happened in subsequent fields because your code is initially bound to controls available on page on the moment jquery code is executing. This was solved earlier with jquery.live functionality, now with jquery.on functionality which makes sure that elements added later on page also work as desired.

> 2) Is there a way to redo this calculation javascript to where it can also run 
>   off the +counter function I am using, so I don't have to make a code for 1-60?

**Answer:** Since it is now refactored as a separate function, you should be able to do that.

> 3) (smaller issue) When the form does duplicate a row, it looks almost identical but the spacing between each input is a little smaller, I can't find anything in my code that would cause this.

**Answer:** This is the 4px whitespace problem. [You can read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248135/negative-left-margin-issue-and-mysterious-4px-difference). I fixed it with assigning `right margin: 19px` to your controls added through DHTML.

> What has been done in the code below to fix the issues?

**Answer:** `jquery.on` is now used in classes to add desired functionality to dynamically added controls. Also, your controls are referenced by css class names now. Moreso, rest of the elements in the same row are referenced through parent control of the container which has caused the action.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 2;
            $("#addButton").click(function () {

                if (counter > 60) {
                    alert("Max 60 Standard Shutters Per Order");
                    return false;
                }

                var newStandardDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                     .attr({
                         "name": 'StandardDiv' + counter, "id": 'StandardDiv' + counter, "class": 'StandardDiv'
                     });

                newStandardDiv.after().html(

                    '<span style="margin-right:19px">Room: ' +
                      '<input class="text sroom" type="text" name="sroom' + counter + '" id="sroom' + counter + '" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px">' +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span style="margin-right:19px;" height="90px">Width: ' +
                     '<input class="text swidth" type="number" name="swidth' +

counter + '" id="swidth' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0"  title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' + '</span>' +
                 '<span style="margin-right:19px">Height: ' +
                  '<input class="text sheight" type="number" name="sheight' +
counter + '" id="sheight' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px"   step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values.">' + '</span>' +
                  '<span style="margin-right:19px">Sq. Ft. Rect: ' +
                   '<input class="text ssqfoot" type="number" name="ssqfoot' +
counter + '" id="ssqfoot' + counter + '" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly />' +
                '</span>' +
                '</div>'
                );
                newStandardDiv.appendTo("#StandardGroup");
                var objDiv = document.getElementById("StandardGroup");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                counter++;
            });

            $("#removeButton").click(function () {
                if (counter == 2) {
                    alert("Nothing To Remove");
                    return false;
                }
                counter--;
                $("#StandardDiv" + counter).remove();
            });
        });

        function calculate(field, name) {
            var parentDiv = $(field).parent().parent();
            let sheight = ((name == "h") ? (parseFloat($(field).val())) : $(parentDiv).find(".sheight").val()) || 0;
            let swidth = ((name == "w") ? (parseFloat($(field).val())) : $(parentDiv).find(".swidth").val()) || 0;
            let swidth_r = 6 * Math.round(swidth / 6);
            let sheight_r = 6 * Math.round(sheight / 6);
            $(parentDiv).find('.ssqfoot').val(sheight_r * swidth_r / 144);
        }

        $(document).on("keyup mouseup", ".sheight", function () {
            calculate($(this), "h");
        });

        $(document).on("keyup mouseup", ".swidth", function () {
            calculate($(this), "w");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="StandardGroup" style="max-height:440px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:2px">
        <div id="StandardDiv1">
            <span style="margin-right:15px">
                Room:
                <input class="text sroom" type="text" name="sroom1" id="sroom1" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px">
            </span>
            <span style="margin-right:15px;" height="90px">
                Width:
                <input class="text swidth" type="number" name="swidth1" id="swidth1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values." value="">
            </span>
            <span style="margin-right:15px">
                Height:
                <input class="text sheight" type="number" name="sheight1" id="sheight1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" step="0.125" min="0" title="Measurements in decimal point values.">
            </span>
            <span style="margin-right:15px">
                Sq. Ft. Rect: <input class="text ssqfoot" type="number" name="ssqfoot1" id="ssqfoot1" style="width:50px; margin-bottom:10px" readonly />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="button light" value="+" id="addButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; margin-left:13px;">
    <input type="button" class="button light" value="-" id="removeButton" style="height:25px; width:25px; padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all your work and responses. Though I know your answers are definitely a more practical method to follow, I just kept scouring the web into the wee hours of the morning until it yielded results.

Through this I did figure out that my form wasn't "recalculating" for the subsequent rows because the trigger loaded with the original page. I then found an "older/obsolete", yet working and effective method to make it trigger again.

I assigned all the height width inputs to class textb.

then I was able to bring it to life with this code.
$(".textB").live("keyup",function(){

Only problem is it would only calculate for the current row... which means if someone made a mistake it wouldn't calculate for it unless they backed up to that row. So... I ended up biting the bullet and made a 1-60 code for each one.

Again, not the most effective way to accomplish the task, but it works. Again, thank you all very much for your help, you guys are awesome. I love this community.

Also, I will do all the research I can before asking anything else, but I may run into some issues trying to make my submit button be able to send the info in an HTML table conditionally on whether these dynamic rows exist or not. Obviously I don't want 55 empty rows if there are only 5 items ordered lol.

I'm guessing it will be a pretty time consuming "if/then" setup.